# Install vmware inside VM instance in GCP. (vm nested)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vmware

I was wondering how do I enable vm nested in compute engine to install vmware inside the instance and simulate labs.
Basically it would be one vm inside another vm.

Answer (score 2):

Google Compute Engine does not provide access to the low level hardware to support VMware virtualization within a virtual machine.

This would be a huge security breach as you could then access other virtual machines running on the same host.

You can install a KVM compatible hypervisor. Hyper-V, ESX and Xen are not supported.

This Google document provides additional details:

[Enabling Nested Virtualization for VM Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances)

Comment: I don't know of any reason why Intel's VT-x instructions would open a security hole here. (After all, they're being used by KVM to do nested virtualization too, and Google has no problem with you doing that.)

Comment: @Dan - you need more than just VT-x to run VMware in a virtual machine. However, that is a topic for a new question.

Comment: Sure, and not wanting to maintain driver support in ESXi for virtio devices is probably the reason it’s not supported. My point is just that there isn’t inherently a security hole if you want to run a hypervisor other than KVM inside a VM.